# You can prove that compacts in the weak topology are limited without the Eberlein-Šmulian theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-topology

You can prove that compacts in the weak topology are bounded without the [Eberlein-Šmulian theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eberlein%E2%80%93%C5%A0mulian_theorem)?

With Smuliam's Theorem this is immediate, because if you assume by contradiction that $K$ is unborded in the norm topology, exists $\{x_n\}_k \subset K$ such that $||x_k||>k$ for all $k$, due to the compactness in the weak topology, being relatively compact, there is a limit point, so the sequence cannot explode in norm. I would like to know if there is any way to do this without using this Theorem?

Comment: Doesn't this follow directly from the uniform boundedness principle?

Comment: And more generally, just if the space is Hausdorff locally convex the result holds. Clearly every weakly compact set is weakly bounded. Mackey's theorem says weakly bounded sets are Mackey-bounded, and a Hausdorff locally convex topology lies between the weak and the Mackey topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I'm missing something subtle, but I think this follows directly from the uniform boundedness principle.  Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $K \subset X$ be weakly compact.  Consider $K$ as a subset of $X^{**}$.  Each $f \in X^*$ is continuous with respect to the weak topology on $X$, so the set $\{f(x) : x \in K\} = f(K)$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ and hence bounded.  Thus the set $K \subset X^{**}$ is pointwise bounded, and so by the uniform boundedness principle it is bounded in norm.  Since the norm on $X^{**}$ agrees with the norm on $X$ (the canonical embedding is an isometry) we have shown that $K$ is bounded in norm.

Comment: Since the dual of a normed space is Banach, this argument doesn't need completeness of $X$, it works for all normed $X$. (I know you know that, but not every reader will.)

Comment: You really need to use $K$ as a subset of $X^{∗∗}$?

Comment: @RicardoFreire: Well, the uniform boundedness principle as I know it is about a set of continuous linear functionals on a Banach space.  The only way I know to identify an element $x \in X$ as a linear functional is to identify it with the functional $f \mapsto f(x)$ in $X^{**}$.

Comment: I just thought of defining for each $x \in K $, $ T_x: E ^ {*} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $T_x(f) = f(x)$ and use the uniform boundedness principle. It's actually the same thing.